# Configuring Enterprise Library with .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, migration, asp.net-core-mvc, enterprise-library

I am in the process of migrating a solution from .NET framework 4.7.1 to .NET Core 2.1 and am having issues with Enterprise Library 6 (Using EnterpriseLibrary.Data.NetCore Nuget Package)

I am attempting to create a database from connection string and register it with Autofac.

The original code looks like this:

```
builder.Register(c => new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create(DefaultConnection) as SqlDatabase).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Where `DefaultConnection` is a string constant representing the `web.config` Connection String.

In the `web.config` I have:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="DefaultConnection" />
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="*****************" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This works fine.

In my .NET Core 2.1 solution I am using the following code

```
builder.Register(_ => new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create(Constants.DefaultConnection) as SqlDatabase).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But this throws the following exception:

```
The connection string for the database 'DefaultConnection' does not exist or does not have a valid provider. 
 - The requested database DefaultConnection is not defined in configuration
```

I have a `web.config` with the same settings in the solution, but it is not being read, I also have a `appsettings.json` with the connection strings.

I have tried the following code using the `appsettings.json`:

```
builder.Register(_ => new SqlDatabase(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Which seems to work, but when I call `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseExtensions.ExecuteSprocAccessor(...)`

I get the exception

```
Parameter discovery is not supported for connections using GenericDatabase.
You must specify the parameters explicitly, or configure the connection to use a type deriving from Database that supports parameter discovery.'
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what the correct way to do this would be?

Comment: Please show "everything".  Aka, show your appsettings.json and web.config.